# Relacion de muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un esquema de la siguiente manera.

```
-tag
name:string
status:boolean
```

---

```
-product.
name:string
status:boolean
```

---

```
-product_tags
product_id
tag_id
```

La relación entre ***product*** y ***tag*** es de muchos a muchos, lo que quiero hacer es poder traer todos los productos con `status=true` y sus tags con `status=true.`

He estado intentando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT pr.*,t.* FROM product pr
inner JOIN product_tags_tag pr_tag ON pr_tag.productId=pr.id 
INNER JOIN tag t ON t.id=pr_tag.tagId
WHERE pr.`status`=TRUE AND t.`status`=TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucioné de esta manera, en vez de hacer `inner join`, se debe utiizar `left join` ya que selecciona los ***productos*** y si hay sus ***tags***.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo que tus tablas: `tag` y `product` tienen una llave primaria denominada `id` que es la vinculación con las llaves foráneas: `product_id` y `tag_id` en la tabla `product_tags` tu consulta debería ser así:

```
SELECT product.name, tag.name
FROM product 
JOIN product_tags ON product.id = product_tags.product_id
JOIN tag ON tag.id = product_tags.tag_id
WHERE product.status = true
AND tags.status = true;
```

Comment: esa no es la consulta que estoy buscando,quiero que me devuelva los productos con status true y de estos solo los tags con status true

Comment: pensaba que por eso coloqué un `and` al final indicando que el `status` de la tabla `tags` sea `true` @DanteAligeri

Comment: eso me devuelve todos los productos que tengas un status true y todos los tags con status true, lo digo por que probe con un producto  con un tag en false, y no me muestra a pesar de que el producto tiene un status true